# Windows written python script can't import pandas or numpy when run on mac ; everything works fine on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, incompatibility

I have written a script that depends on importing pandas and random libraries as a first step. However, when I try to run this script in python3 on a Mac computer,

I think I could just get away with using pandas and without importing numpy at all, but when I do, the same problem occurs, just with pandas instead of numpy. I get the Same ModuleNotFoundError. So there's something wrong with the way that I'm trying to import the libraries.

I'm confused because everything works fine on multiple windows machines. I can't imagine that numpy or pandas are restricted to Windows only.

This is how I'm importing the libraries.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
```

I expect this to import numpy, pandas, and random without comment, but I actually get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "pandasplay.py," line 1, in <module> 
    import numpy as np 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Did something go wrong with installation of python three on the mac? I'm using Python 3.7.3.

Comment: Do you have the module directory specified in your path?

Comment: I'll check the next time I have access to the end user's computer.

Comment: @LeeGarcon that would be something that looks a lot like this (?):

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: Did ypu `pip install pandas numpy?`

Comment: Can you give us the contents of your `site-packages`?

Comment: It's working now. The macs I was working on had python 2.7 installed; I wrote the program on a windows machine using python 3.7. To solve the problem, I installed python3, used `pip3 install pandas numpy` (since pip by itself was installing the modules to 2.7), and then `pip3 install xlrd`. After that, was good to go. Thanks all for your help! Not sure why this was so confusing; I think import by itself just worked on my windows machine. Also, new to python, definitely new to using across operating systems, so thanks for your patience.